# Designing a unique id reliably based on a String date?

Tags: java, design, android, hashing

I am creating an Android application that sets alarms based on the String date of a list of Objects (PendingIntents, with each taking in an id, that is an integer). In order to cancel the PendingIntent, I must know the PendingIntent's id.

I am having trouble of figuring out a way to generate a unique id reliably with a minimal chance of collisions. If I simply convert the String date to miliseconds, I believe that would not be reliable since the user can change timezones on their phone and the computer can make timestamp computations that are off by a few miliseconds.

Comment: Define "minimal". A random 32-bit integer has a chance of collision so low that you're virtually guaranteed to never have that problem as long as your app lives - is that not enough for you?

Comment: @KilianFoth Gotcha. Should I use Java's hashCode function to convert the String into an integer or use the timestamp in miliseconds as the id?

Comment: One option could be the `randomUUID` method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982748/create-a-guid-in-java/2982750#2982750

Comment: timestamp in seconds.

Comment: You can use `uptimeMillis()` or one of the other monotonic clocks. They won't go backwards except on reboot, and I'm pretty sure PendingIntents don't survive reboot.